# R - retrieve specific information from several columns

Tags: r, intervals, mapply

I have a huge dataframe `df` which includes information about overlapping intervals (A) and (B) and on which chromosome (chrom) they were located. There is also information about a value (level of gene expression) observed over interval (A).

```
chrom value    Astart      Aend    Bstart      Bend
 chr1     0         0  54519752     17408     17431
 chr1     0         0  54519752     17368     17391
 chr1     0         0  54519752    567761    567783
chr11     0         2  93466832    568111    568133
chr11     0         2  93466832    568149    568171
chr11     0         2  93466832   1880734   1880756
chr11     4  93466844  93466880  93466856  93466878
chr11     2  93466885 135006516  93466889  93466911
chr11     2  93466885 135006516  94199710  94199732
```

Note that the same interval may appear several times, for instance, an interval (B) will have been reported two times if it overlapped with two (A) intervals:

```
Astart(1)=========================Aend1    Astart(2)========================Aend(2)
          Bstart(1)=======================================Bend(1)

chrom value Astart   Aend  Bstart  Bend
chr1      0      0     25      15    35    #A(1) and B(1) overlap
chr1      1     28     45      15    35    #A(2) and B(1) overlap
```

Likewise, an interval (A) will have been reported two or more times if it overlapped with two or more (B) intervals:

```
Astart(3)===================================================================Aend(3)
          Bstart(2)=========Bend(2)  Bstart(3)===========Bend(3) Bstart(4)===============Bend(4)

chrom value Astart   Aend  Bstart  Bend
chr4      0     10    100      15    25    #A(3) and B(2) overlap
chr4      0     10    100      30    75    #A(3) and B(3) overlap
chr4      3     10    100      80   120    #A(3) and B(4) overlap
```

My goal is to output all the individual positions from intervals (B) and the corresponding values from (A). I have a piece of code that beautifully outputs all the relevant positions in (B):

```
position <- unlist(mapply(seq, ans$Bstart, ans$Bend - 1))
> head(position)
[1] 17408 17409 17410 17411 17412 17413
```

The problem with this is that it is not enough to retrieve the chromosome information back from there. I need to check chromosome information AND position at the same time when I list these positions. That is because the same position integer may occur on several chromosomes, so I can't afterwards just run something like `for position %in% range(Astart, Aend) output $chrom, $value` (dummy code).

How can I retrieve `(chrom, position, value)` at the same time?

The expected result would be something like this:

```
> head(expected_result)
chrom    position   value
chr1     17408      0
chr1     17409      0
chr1     17410      0
chr1     17411      0
chr1     17412      0
chr1     17413      0
#skipping some lines to show another part of the dataframe
chr11    93466856   4
chr11    93466857   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `ddply` might be more elegant, but the logic would be the same:

```
dfA = read.table(textConnection("chrom value    Astart      Aend    Bstart      Bend
 chr1     0         0  54519752     17408     17431
 chr1     0         0  54519752     17368     17391
 chr1     0         0  54519752    567761    567783
chr11     0         2  93466832    568111    568133
chr11     0         2  93466832    568149    568171
chr11     0         2  93466832   1880734   1880756
chr11     4  93466844  93466880  93466856  93466878
chr11     2  93466885 135006516  93466889  93466911
chr11     2  93466885 135006516  94199710  94199732"), header = TRUE)


dfB = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
        apply(dfA, MARGIN = 1,  FUN = function(x) {
          cbind(mapply(seq, 
                       as.numeric(x['Bstart']),
                       as.numeric(x['Bend']) - 1),
                x['chrom'], x['value'])
        }
        )))
lapply(dfB, typeof)
```

Comment: Thank you for putting an end to 48 hours of frustration!! :D

Comment: Do you know how I could avoid getting all output values between " "?

Comment: @biohazard Just wrap the whole thing in an `as.data.frame`.